# How to enable button after filling text box using c#

Tags: c#

As per **AntLaC** [link suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12861429/how-do-i-make-that-only-if-the-user-entered-any-text-to-textbox-so-the-button1-w) I have tried but it is not working in my coding. please help me  where i made mistake please let me know. Below is back end code

```
 protected void txtCardHolderName1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtCardHolderName1.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            btnNext.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            btnNext.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

aspx code

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upServiceFee" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCardHolderName1" runat="server" CssClass="txtbox" Width="220px" ValidationGroup="ServiceFee" MaxLength="100" AutoPostBack="true" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" autocomplete="off" OnTextChanged="txtCardHolderName1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" CssClass="btn btnBlue btnStep" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" CausesValidation="true"  ValidationGroup="ServiceFee" Enabled="false" />
```

Comment: ok what is an issue?

Comment: it is not showing any error........... but submit button not enabled even after entering text

Comment: is your txtCardHolderName1_TextChanged event is triggered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got My answer with the help of javascript,Thank you so much for helping me. Just i put below code in postback

```
string var = ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnNext, "").ToString();
            btnNext.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript :if ( Page_ClientValidate() ){this.disabled=true; this.value='Please Wait...';" + var + "};");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle TextChanged event even when you don’t use the AutoPostBack property.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to change the if statement to:

```
if(textBox != null)
```

Comment: no..... it is not working....because textbox is under update panel .......please any other solution.....